# Large Files Uploading on Angular 4+ to Django

Tags: django, angular, angular2-forms, ng-file-upload, angular2-http

Currently I am uploading file using `angular2-http-file-upload` and send it to django back-end and it work fine with small files here is how I done it but when uploading large file 35Mb-600Mb its throwing exception from django sometimes it run fine local server but on cloud it always throwing exception

Edited: I already set the client max body size in nginx.conf file

**my-upload-item.ts**

```
import { UploadItem } from 'angular2-http-file-upload';
export class MyUploadItem extends UploadItem {
  constructor(file: any) {
    super();
    this.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/training/save/';
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

**my-component.ts**

```
submit2() {
    // ///////////////
    // Upload File
    // ///////////////
    let uploadTrainingFile = (<HTMLInputElement>window.document.getElementById('fileInput1')).files[0];
    console.log('file tarining   ', uploadTrainingFile);
    let myUploadItem1 = new MyUploadItem(uploadTrainingFile);
    myUploadItem1.formData = { FormDataKey: 'Form Data Value', 'category': this.category, 'type': 'Training File' };  // (optional) form data can be sent with file

    this.uploaderService.onSuccessUpload = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      // success callback
      console.log('successs  ', response.path, response.type);
      console.log('seed step')
    };
    this.uploaderService.onErrorUpload = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      // error callback
      console.log('error  ', response);
    };
    this.uploaderService.onCompleteUpload = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      // complete callback, called regardless of success or failure
      console.log('callback  ', response);
    };
    this.uploaderService.onProgressUpload = (item, percentComplete) => {
      // progress callback
      console.log('progresss  ', percentComplete)
    };

    if (typeof uploadTrainingFile != 'undefined' ) {
      this.uploaderService.upload(myUploadItem1);
      console.log('uploaded');
      // if (this.uploaderService.onProgressUpload)
    }
    console.log('end func submit 2');
  }
```

**Django View to Save File**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_file(request):
    try:
    #     print ('Save File  ', request.FILES)
        category = request.data['category']
        type = request.data['type']
        file = request.FILES['file']
        save_file_addresss = './training_files/' + category + '/' + file.name

        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(save_file_addresss), exist_ok=True)

        with open(save_file_addresss, 'a+') as sv_file:
            for line in file:
                sv_file.write((line.decode("utf-8")).rstrip() + '\n')

        return Response({'path': save_file_addresss, 'type': type}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except:
        return Response({'msg': 'fail'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Edited:** 
nginx.conf
I am using nginx and its configration is

```
server {

    listen 80 ;
    server_name reviewsai.com www.reviewsai.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://150.60.20.100:8100;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size 500M;
    }
}
```

**gunicorn file is :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn ReviewsAI.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3
    --timeout 3600
```

**Django Setings are :**

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 618659840
```

Comment: What is the exception from Django? There are two Django settings that you can set for bigger file sizes. Also what web server are you running?

Comment: The problem is quite likely to be in your web server config as there's usually a maximum uploaded file size, even if it's not explicitly set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 error with large media files on django server running nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770938/403-error-with-large-media-files-on-django-server-running-nginx)

Comment: Michael Gecht can you please tell me or send some link for large files settings.. thanks

Comment: @MatthewDaly, I alreadey set client max body size in server configration file,

Comment: @NazirAhmed Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770938/403-error-with-large-media-files-on-django-server-running-nginx). I've linked the Django settings in my answer.

What web server are you using? `nginx`, `apache2`? Can you provide the settings that you've set for that? Make sure to also set the Django settings.

Comment: I am using nginx and you can see config files in above edited question

Comment: @NazirAhmed You don't specify whether that's the application server or the web server. The problem could be in either - if you're using Nginx and Gunicorn, it could be in either Nginx's config, or Gunicorn's

Comment: I edited the question you can see the guicorn file settings, I don't know what went wrong while uploading file, I think it may be from web server

Comment: What is the exact error message that Django provides you? Could you add that to your question?